# Django: Reverse not found

Tags: python, django

Excuse my ignorance, but I am trying to redirect to the login page showing that some errors happened but don't know why this django error shows up:

```
NoReverseMatch at /dologin

Reverse for 'show_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'error': 'Login Failed'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

When called this line:

```
return redirect('show_login', error="Login Failed")
```

I don't even understand what the reverse is. I just want to send the error to show login and then catch it:

```
def show_login(request, error=False):
    return render(request, 'main/login.html', {"error": error})
```

And dologin is mapped from the urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^dologin', 'main.views.login', name='dologin'),
...
```

Edit: Might it have something to do with this:
I first had:

```
url(r'^login', 'main.views.show_login', name='login'),
```

but when changed to

```
url(r'^login', 'main.views.show_login', name='show_login'),
```

the error was:

```
everse for 'show_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'error': 'Login Failed'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['login']
```

Comment: `/dologin` is registered in `urls.py` ?

Comment: @Lafada yes it is. url(r'^dologin', 'main.views.login', name='dologin'),

Comment: will you please try this >>> from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
>>> get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.keys() and see its showing `dologin` in it or not.

Comment: @Lafada ['index', <function show_setup at 0x10c3d0a28>, <function login at 0x10c3d0848>, <function get at 0x10c3d0aa0>, <function show_login at 0x10c3d08c0>, <function index at 0x10c3d07d0>, <function logout at 0x10c3d0938>, 'logout', 'show_login', 'login', <function setup at 0x10c3d09b0>, 'setup', 'show_setup']

Comment: use this code in `manage.py shell`

Comment: @Lafada actually the function is not called dologin, it is called login, but mapped to dologin because to the login page I have /login url. and as the login function is already called "login", I called show_login for showing the template

Answer (score 0):

Your `show_login` view does not take any arguments, but you are trying to pass an `error` argument. I'm not clear what you are trying to do, but it will work if you take that argument out.

Comment: of course a REAL error happened when the client tried to log in so i return an error variable for it to show up in the views. The user entered an incorrect password and that's the error that must be retrieved. If no error happens, error is passed to false. I am taking error which is set to False by default (request, error=False). Where I think I am not taking it is in the URL mapper. @DanielRoseman